# Cannot insert values from form using Play for Scala and Anorm

Tags: mysql, forms, scala, playframework-2.0

When I enter data into the form fields and click on "Add book" button it happens nothing... The entered data into fields it's not added into the database, I receive no error and I don't know what I'm doing wrong...

I have the following controller

```
package controllers
import play.api.data.Form
import play.api.data.Forms._
import play.api.mvc.{Action, Controller}
import anorm.NotAssigned
import play.api.Play.current
import play.api.i18n.Messages.Implicits._
import models.Buch

object Book extends Controller{

 val addBookForm = Form(
     mapping(
         "name" -> nonEmptyText,
         "author" -> nonEmptyText,
         "category" -> nonEmptyText,
         "read" -> boolean,
         "amount" -> number
     )(Buch.apply)(Buch.unapply)
 )  

 def add = Action {
     Ok(views.html.book(addBookForm))
 }


 def addBuch() = Action { implicit request =>
  addBookForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
    errors => BadRequest,
    {
      case Buch(name, author, category, read, amount) =>
      Buch.addBook(Buch(name, author, category, read, amount))
      Ok("Book successfully added!")

     }
    )
   }
 }
```

The following model

```
 package models

 import play.api.db._
 import play.api.Play.current

 import anorm._
 import anorm.SqlParser._

 case class Buch(name:String, author:String, category:String, read:Boolean, amount: Int)

 object Buch{

     val simple = {
         get[String]("buch.name") ~
         get[String]("buch.auhtor") ~
         get[String]("buch.category") ~
         get[Boolean]("buch.read") ~
         get[Int]("buch.amount") map {
       case name~author~category~read~amount => Buch(name, author, category, read, amount)
       }
     }

def findAll(): Seq[Buch] = {
   DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
     SQL("select * from buch").as(Buch.simple *)
   }
}

def addBook(buch:Buch): Unit = {
   DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
     SQL("insert into buch(name, author, category, read, amount) values ({name}, {author}, {category}, {read}, {amount})").on(
       'name -> buch.name,
       'author -> buch.author,
       'category -> buch.category,
       'read -> buch.read,
       'amount -> buch.amount
    ).executeUpdate()
  }
 }
}
```

The following sql script

```
  # Buch schema

  # --- !Ups

  CREATE TABLE Buch (
      id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      author varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      category varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      read boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      amount int(11) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (id)
  );


  # --- !Downs

  DROP TABLE Buch;
```

The following view

```
  @(form: Form[Buch])(implicit messages: Messages)

  @main("Welcome to Play 2.0") {

  @helper.form(action = routes.Book.addBuch) {
       @helper.inputText(form("name"))
       @helper.inputText(form("author"))
       @helper.inputText(form("category"))
       @helper.inputText(form("read"))
       @helper.inputText(form("amount"))
       <input type="submit" value="Add book"/>
   }

 }
```

If I modify the model, for example creating it with only 3 parameters, name, author and category the method addBook will insert the data into my database.

Can anyone please tell what am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Add debug to check whether `addBook` is called. If yes try to execute an insert with same values in your DB client to check what happen. According that you could get more help.

Comment: It seems that my model (I think) does not "see" boolean data type...so that's the reason why it was not working...I changed it into varchar and now the input from form is stored in my database.

Comment: These types, BOOL and BOOLEAN are synonyms for TINYINT(1). A value of zero is considered false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mysql, `read` is a reserved word. See [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html).

```
CREATE TABLE Buch (
  id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  author varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  category varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  read boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',  
  amount int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

You should replace it with some non-reserved word (e.g. book_read) or escape it by putting in backticks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Buch (
  id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  author varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  category varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `read` boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  amount int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Edit:

Anorm does not provide default mapping from mysql boolean to scala boolean. From its [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaAnorm#JDBC-mappings):

> It’s possible to add custom mapping, for example if underlying DB
>   doesn’t support boolean datatype and returns integer instead. To do
>   so, you have to provide a new implicit conversion for Column[T], where
>   T is the target Scala type:
>
> ```
> import anorm.Column
>
> // Custom conversion from JDBC column to Boolean
> implicit def columnToBoolean: Column[Boolean] = 
>   Column.nonNull1 { (value, meta) =>
>     val MetaDataItem(qualified, nullable, clazz) = meta
>     value match {
>       case bool: Boolean => Right(bool) // Provided-default case
>       case bit: Int      => Right(bit == 1) // Custom conversion
>       case _             => 
>        Left(TypeDoesNotMatch(s"Cannot convert $value: ${value.asInstanceOf[AnyRef].getClass} to Boolean 
>  for column $qualified"))
>     }
>   }
> ```

Also see [this discussion](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/1405) on Anorm - Mysql Boolean.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it did not worked...I replaced the reserved book as you said but nothing... I noticed that if I modify the type of book_read into String for example, it works but for boolean it doesn't.
Why is this happening?

Thank you!

Comment: @Hkt The anorm documentation has info on how to use boolean type with databases that don't support it. Edited the answer for same.